# Optimizing PHP string concatenation

Tags: php, optimization

This post is not really a question, but it could be useful to share some coding tips.

Here is the one I'd like to share with you. I'm going to show 4 examples that do the same thing. But only the last one will be the best.

```
$foo = 'John SMITH';

echo "Hello $foo, welcome on my website.";

echo "Hello " . $foo . " welcome on my website.";

echo 'Hello ' . $foo . ' welcome on my website.';

echo 'Hello ', $foo , ' welcome on my website.';
```

I'm sure you all know that `echo '$foo'` won't work, but still, I'm pretty sure that you use double quote to display a simple information. 
**This is bad**.

Well let's begin : The first one is bad (as well as the second) because using double quote forces php to scan the string to look for a substitution to be done (I mean a variable).

The second one is a little better, since php has no replacement to do.

The third one, is better because of simple quote, so that the language knows he can just send the text without processing, but the "bad" thing is the use of concatenation (dot operator, like in the second example).

The last one uses simple quote, and the coma operator. Why is this solution better?

Well, what happens when Using the third solution?

php creates a string, containing `"Hello "`, then it has to enlarge it, to put the content of foo variable ("John SMITH"), and then, enlarge it again to put `" Welcome on my website."` sentence.
Then, `echo` can use this, to ... echo it :)

Whereas in the 4th one, the only thing to do for `echo` is to send "Hello ", then $foo's content, then " Welcome on my website." to the output, and that is all!
Because echo just has to send the text, without creating a string that will have to be enlarged to contain the whole text (that would have been concave, which has to be grown (because of concatenation) and then displayed.

I'll try to find back some benchmarks and put them here.

Fell free to comment or react, and excuse my English, this is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Do you have performance data on this?

Comment: This is useful information, but you should present it in the question / answer format of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Rob , quite contrary, this information is completely useless. In the real life you will gain **nothing** from such "optimizations".

Comment: If you concatenations would be used in some text analysis, then it could be useful. But you have brought here bad examples.

Comment: thanks @Gangnus for that pseudo-positive comment :-)
Nevertheless, I'de rather bury this very old post of mine though.

Comment: It is not pseudo-positive. I have plused the post and gave a reopen. I personally can see the use in optimizing. But if you want to have positive reputation here, your question should be really a question and you examples should be really exemplar. If, you would workbench the time using cycles (1000x, for example) and use echo only for output, they would see the usefulness better. Or even better if you'd have a practical example where concatenation speed is critical. Not many people have imagination. It is as it is and we have to work with them, you don't have another better public.

Comment: We have not only to do the work, but to sell it, as well. You've done only the first part. It's my usual fault, too, so I feel with you.

Comment: considering hiphop's HORRIBLE string performance, i wonder how much this post's info can help

Answer (score 25):

**It is completely irrelevant which solution performs better.** Computers are blazing fast and CPU cycles are cheap, therefore millisecond optimizations are pointless. The only real optimization is the one that helps **you** read the code faster, so you can save your precious time and focus on actually delivering working code.

Comment: You guys are about 2-3 years behind. Tablets and phones are not so fast. And optimization is extremely important there. In Android/iOS the primary optimization is by processor/battery time, not by readability.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I haven't noticed, that the post IS 4 years in the past.

Comment: @Gangnus: Two points: 1. This is PHP, so it's probably going to be run on a remote machine and then have the content served to the client; 2. Even if that weren't the case, the difference in performance is so small that it is not perceptible - even after hundreds of thousands of loops you'll still be looking at *maybe* millisecond differences. A 70s era Soviet Calculator wouldn't notice this trivial a micro-optimization... and on top of that `echo` is one of the few functions that will almost NEVER be seen in a massive loop.

Comment: you guys... even people not working for facebook are confronted to problem where concatenation speed of a string will matter. there can be noticeable differences in seconds on as little as 5000 iterations of a dotted concatenation. I mean, you really think optimization is irrelevant? no questionning why computers start being so slow after three of four years, sloppy people do slower and slower code all the time...

Comment: Late to the party, but I'm currently sitting with a problem where no more than 1,500 iterations of dot concatenation adds half a second of execution time. This is an *obscene* amount of time depending on the application.

Answer (score 25):

Creating a small (but still sucking :) benchmark and running it yields the following results:

```
0.0022029876709
0.00211095809937
0.00213599205017
0.00551700592041
```

The last method is clearly the slowest.

Answer (score 11):

The three rules of optimization are:

1. Don't Optimize Yet.
2. Don't Optimize Yet.
3. Don't Optimize Yet.

Save it for the LAST thing you do, only after learning where the slowdowns are.

Otherwise, you will be putting the cart before the horse, so to speak.

Comment: I hear you, but if changing one of your habits results in faster code, why not do it? It isn't harder to write or maintain, you are just doing things the right way first.

Comment: You're spent more time reading these comments than will ever by saved across all the apps you ever write in your entire lifetime by switching from " to '.

Answer (score 8):

In practice, this almost always isn't going to be your primary bottleneck.

http://www.procata.com/blog/archives/2005/03/08/microbenchmarks-of-single-and-double-qouting/

Answer (score 7):

It's not worth it. You may experience some 0,1% speedup (don't take it literally; a negligible speedup) for your whole application even if you manage to make string concatenation faster by 30%. Most of the time will be spent in DB queries or more sophisticated logic.